# How to get user's email from a messaging extension query with Azure bot framework?

Tags: python, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have created an Azure bot for doing a quick search with the messaging extension feature, but I need the user's email to corroborate some data.

I used the

```
print(turn_context.activity.from_property.id)
```

output:

```
29:xxxxxx_-ZeW4Q6vIILx8BGjD-xxx88tLxqZFPYPxxxl_42i-siINFZkxxxfgbgGczHXZxx5crxx_xxxxxxxxxx
```

Not sure how to convert or cross-match this string to get the user's email.

I'm passing the "TeamsActivityHandler" into my SearchBasedMessagingExtension class.
Also, using the search_based_messaging_extension sampler from github to do the query.

Is there another way?

Edit:100721

I tried just adding the function like the following but the function is never called.

```
class SearchBasedMessagingExtension(TeamsActivityHandler):

async def _show_members(self, turn_context: TurnContext ):
    member = await TeamsInfo.get_member(turn_context, turn_context.activity.from_property.id)
    print(member)

async def on_teams_messaging_extension_query(self, turn_context: TurnContext, query: MessagingExtensionQuery):
    search_query = str(query.parameters[0].value).strip()
    if search_query == "":
        await turn_context.send_activity(MessageFactory.text("You cannot enter a blank string for the search"))
        return
    
    
    print(turn_context.activity.from_property.id)
```

So I then call it after the if condition like so:

```
async def on_teams_messaging_extension_query(self, turn_context: TurnContext, query: MessagingExtensionQuery):
    search_query = str(query.parameters[0].value).strip()
    if search_query == "":
        await turn_context.send_activity(MessageFactory.text("You cannot enter a blank string for the search"))
        return
    print(await self._show_members(turn_context))

    print(turn_context.activity.from_property.id)
```

and received the next error:

> source is not a known attribute of class <class 'botbuilder.schema.teams._models_py3.TeamsChannelData'> and will be ignored

Answer (score 1):

You can call get_member to ask for the member(s) .

```
async def _show_members(
self, turn_context: TurnContext ):
member = await TeamsInfo.get_member(turn_context, turn_context.activity.from_property.id)
```

See this [python sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=python#get-single-member-details) from the documentation

Comment: Hi, I edited my question with the function you suggested and the error I'm receiving after it. The output says "source is not a known attribute of class <class 'botbuilder.schema.teams._models_py3.TeamsChannelData'> and will be ignored". Not really sure how to handle this

Comment: Please go through the following sample - [teams-conversation-bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/28a039d99221ec6819f08659467363e9bb5913b9/samples/python/57.teams-conversation-bot/bots/teams_conversation_bot.py#L158)

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft, I haven't tried the example above because it is a conversation with the bot while I'm using a messaging extension. What I discover is that I could use sample 52 using an azure active directory as identity provider and now retrieve the user info.